# spring boot adding data to DB for specific request not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

`i have Class Customer and Rooms and it is working fine with adding deleting etc. but now i want that a person can add a Room under Customer name for and this will have a table in DB so i can show the table in Interface..

**This is my RoomLogs Class**

```
package com.example.Market;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table
public class RoomLogs {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "RoomLogs",
            sequenceName = "RoomLogs",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "RoomLogs")
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Kunde kunde;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Room room;

    public RoomLogs(Kunde kunde, Room room) {
        this.kunde = kunde;
        this.room = room;
    }

    public RoomLogs() {

    }
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<String> addLogs(@RequestParam int KundenID, @RequestParam int RoomId) {
    this.roomLogsService.addLogs(KundenID, RoomId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Added");
}
```

this is the BL

```
public void addLogs(int kundenId, int RoomId) {
    Optional<Kunde> k = this.kundeRespo.findById(kundenId);
    Optional<Room> r = this.roomRespo.findById(RoomId);
    
    if (k.isPresent() && r.isPresent()) {
        Kunde kunde = k.get();
        Room room = r.get();
        RoomLogs roomL = new RoomLogs(kunde, room);
        room.setFree(true);
        this.roomLogsRespo.save(roomL);
    }
}
```

this is the HTTP Req i am sending
POST http://localhost:8081/api/v1/Logs/add
Content-Type: application/json

`{   "KundenID": 20,`

`"RoomID": 1 }`

i tried my best to solve this problem but no luck..
if anyone know where i am wrong it will be helpfull..

Add the Data in the Database.

to add data in the table

add the data in DB with Add request

Answer (score 1):

You should add `@JoinColumn` annotations to specify the foreign keys:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class RoomLogs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "kunde_id")
    private Kunde kunde;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    //other methods
}
```

Also, your **Kunde** (Customer) entity has a collection of **RoomLogs** so you should set up a bidirectional relationship between **Kunde** and **RoomLogs**:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Kunde {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    // Other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kunde")
    private List<RoomLogs> roomLogs = new ArrayList<>();

    // other methods including constructors, setters, getters
}
```

you have set up bidirectional relationship with **Room** entity as well so you also need to update **Room** entity similarly:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    // Other fields and annotations

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    private List<RoomLogs> roomLogs = new ArrayList<>();

    // other methods including constructors, setters, getters
}
```

Also make sure that your database configuration is properly set up in your application (such as in application.properties or application.yml), including the JDBC URL, username, and password.

Comment: I tried this too but still not working getting the Error.. 

POST http://localhost:8081/api/v1/Logs/add
HTTP/1.1 400 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 12 Aug 2023 18:38:29 GMT
Connection: close
{
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "path": "/api/v1/Logs/add"
}
for other like deleting adding costumer,rooms it is working
DELETE http://localhost:8081/api/v1/kunde/20
HTTP/1.1 200

Comment: The HTTP 400 Bad Request error is a general indication that the server received a request it could not understand or process due to malformed syntax. I can be wrong but this error is not directly related to the logic and database configuration or entity relationships.
@ShameerRiaz please follow below answer, as the answer is long and has code examples, I created another separate answer.
Also, if my answer helped, you can accept the answer as it may help me and others, seeking similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the data in JSON format, but your **addLogs** method in the controller is using `@RequestParam` annotations. If you're sending JSON data, you should use the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<String> addLogs(@RequestBody Map<String, Integer> requestData) {
    int kundenID = requestData.get("KundenID");
    int roomID = requestData.get("RoomID");

    //print to see if you are gettng the JSON data correctly.
    System.out.println("Received JSON data: " + requestData);
    System.out.println("Extracted kundenID: " + kundenID);
    System.out.println("Extracted roomID: " + roomID);
    
    this.roomLogsService.addLogs(kundenID, roomID);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Added");
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to use @RequestParam in your controller method, you can update your controller method like below:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<String> addLogs(
        @RequestParam("KundenID") int kundenID,
        @RequestParam("RoomID") int roomID) {
    this.roomLogsService.addLogs(kundenID, roomID);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Added");
}
```

for testing in for example, Postman, make sure you're sending the data as form-data.  Follow these steps:

1. Choose the HTTP method as POST.
2. Enter the URL: http://localhost:8081/api/v1/Logs/add
3. In the "Body" tab, select "form-data".
4. Add a key-value pair: **KundenID** as Key and desired customer ID(for example 20) as Value
5. Add another key-value pair: **RoomID** as Key and desired room ID(for example 1) as Value

After following above steps, you can send the POST request with the form-data parameters. Ensure that the parameter names in postman (**KundenID** and **RoomID**) match exactly as defined in your controller method: `@RequestParam("KundenID") int kundenID, @RequestParam("RoomID") int roomID)`

Comment: Problem is solved my adding the @RequestParam("KundenID") 
and there were @Autowired Anotation missing in the RoomLogs Service for the RoomRespo. thanks for the Help.